# Is it possible to limit the accessible fonts for some GUI (GTK) program?

Tags: linux, x11, fonts, fontconfig

Because of different reasons, it is useful to limit particular program from accessing all installed in the system fonts.

For example, some programs works very slow when big amount of fonts are installed in the system.

Or some fonts are not useful for some programs and the UX will be better with less fonts visible in the selection dialogs.

On the other hand, some tasks (design for example) needs very big amount of fonts installed in the system.

So, is it possible to limit the accessible fonts for particular program? How?

Or possibly limit the fonts for particular user and run the program as this user?

The OS is Linux, X11 (XFCE if matters).